# Cut & paste values from two data frames for matched values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

What I need is pandas.merge but I also require the rows which were not matched as separate df. I will explain with an example:

I have two Dataframes which are similar to this:

df_1-

```
item     Amount
Ball       15
Ball       12
Ball       10
Pen         3
Pen         2
Kite       15
```

df_2-

```
item   Code   Amount   
Ball   Y       10         
Pen    V       3  
Pen    E       7
```

what I want to obtain is to compare the two dataframe and combine matched `amount + item` (as I dont have code in both the dataframes) along with the `code` column. I can achieve it through merge in pandas. But I also need the entries that are not in dataframe 1 but which are in dataframe 2 and vice versa. For instance Pen of amount 7 is not in Dataframe 1 and Kite from df_1 is not in df_2.

So I need 3 dataframes like this:

```
DataFrame 1: Matched entries

item    Amount   Code   
Ball     10       Y
Pen      3        V


DataFrame 2: items in df_1 but not in df_2
item     Amount
Ball       15
Ball       12
Pen         2
Kite       15

Dataframe 3: item in df_2 not in df_1
item  Code   Amount   
Pen    E       7
```

I may get this by going to row by row but is there a simple method to get instant result just like merge.

Comment: Does `pd.merge(df1, df2, how='outer', ...)` return an acceptable result?

Comment: @Ankur Yeah. I just found out there was 'outer' with an 'indicator'. Got it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2020/02/joins-in-pandas-master-the-different-types-of-joins-in-python/ refer to this link. This might be what you are looking for. Yes there are straightaway functions for it.

Comment: Thanks what I have looking for was ```how='outer', indicator=True```